# How to ignore invalid XML in JSF?

Tags: xml, jsf-2, custom-component

Is it possible to ignore invalid xml-syntax in jsf-files?

I'm writing my own components is jsf 2 and want to create a dynamic table, so i want to render tr- and td-tags conditional. I've tried `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{someCondition}"><tr></h:panelGroup>` (same with `</tr>`) and `<c:if test="#{someCondition}"><tr></c:if>` (same with `</tr>`) though its bad to mix jstl with jsf.

I am getting a `javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing [...] The element type "tr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</tr>"`.

Anybody knows how to ignore the invalid xml oder how solve this problem in any other way?

Answer (score 2):

it's a dirty hack but use:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{bean.row}" />
```

in your page, and

```
public String getRow() {
    return condition ? "" : "<tr>";
}
```

in your Bean. Same with `</tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it. You can set DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER - true in web.xml and problem get away, but on the other hand this downgrade jsf version to 1.2.